# How to fill column based on the condition in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill records one column based on some condition but I am not getting the result. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

df:

```
applied_sql_function1     and_or_not_oprtor_pre    comb_fld_order_1
 CASE WHEN                                    
 WHEN                      AND                     
 WHEN                      AND                          
 WHEN                      
 WHEN                      AND
 WHEN                      OR                      
 WHEN  
 WHEN                                                 dummy
 WHEN                                                 dummy
 WHEN
```

Expected Output:

```
applied_sql_function1     and_or_not_oprtor_pre    comb_fld_order_1     new
 CASE WHEN                                                              CASE WHEN
 WHEN                      AND                                      
 WHEN                      AND                          
 WHEN                                                                   WHEN
 WHEN                      AND
 WHEN                      OR                      
 WHEN                                                                   WHEN
 WHEN                                                 dummy
 WHEN                                                 dummy
 WHEN                                                                   WHEN
```

I have written some logic for this but it is not working:

```
            df_main1['new'] =''
            for index,row in df_main1.iterrows():
                new = ''
                if((str(row['applied_sql_function1']) != '') and (str(row['and_or_not_oprtor_pre']) == '') and (str(row['comb_fld_order_1']) == '')):
                    new += str(row['applied_sql_function1'])
                    print(new)

                if(str(row['applied_sql_function1']) != '') and (str(row['and_or_not_oprtor_pre']) != ''):
                    new += ''
                    print(new)

                else:
                    new += ''

                row['new'] = new

            print(df_main1['new'])
```

Comment: Whats your logic for filling new column?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I have written the logic in my code. Can you please check and let me know if you are not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Go with `np.where` all the way! It's easy to understand and vectorized, so the performance is good on really large datasets.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df['new'] = ''
df['new'] = np.where((df['and_or_not_oprtor_pre'] == '') & (df['comb_fld_order_1'] == ''), df['applied_sql_function1'], df['new'])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Using, [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
mask = df.and_or_not_oprtor_pre.fillna("").eq("") \
       & df.comb_fld_order_1.fillna("").eq("")

df.loc[mask, 'new'] = df.loc[mask, 'applied_sql_function1']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it would work in a quick way

```
indexes = df.index[(df['and_or_not_oprtor_pre'].isna()) & (df['comb_fld_order_1'].isna())]
df.loc[indexes, 'new'] = df.loc[indexes, 'applied_sql_function1']
```